# Irish Citizenship: Residency Requirements

Tags: citizenship, residency, uk-citizens, ireland

I'm looking at possibly applying for a job in Dublin and would be interested in obtaining Irish citizenship. I'm a UK citizen, so getting job permits for Ireland is pretty easy.
I travel a fair amount for work and am slightly confused by the requirements.

https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/becoming_an_irish_citizen_through_naturalisation.html#l6615c

Here's a concrete example.

- Year 1: Spent 300 days in Ireland (more than six weeks away).
- Year 2: Spent 300 days in Ireland (more than six weeks away).
- Year 3: Spent 300 days in Ireland (more than six weeks away).
- Year 4: Spent 300 days in Ireland (more than six weeks away).
- Year 5: Spent 330 days in Ireland (less than six weeks away).

Would I be eligible for (the residency part of) Irish citizenship?

> You must have lived in the State for a certain length of time. The
> specific requirements are that you:
>
> - Have a period of 365 days* (1 year) continuous reckonable residence in the State immediately before the date of your application for
>   naturalisation and
> - During the 8 years before that, have had a total reckonable residence in the State of 1,460 days* (4 years)
>
> You can leave Ireland for up to 6 weeks (in total) per year and still
> be considered resident in that year. If you leave for more than 6
> weeks in one year, you should not count this period when you are
> calculating your reckonable residence.
>
> Altogether you must have 5 years (5 x 365 days*) reckonable residence out of the last 9 years. *You must add 1 day for any period which includes 29 February (a leap year).

Up until the final part, all seems ok:

- I need to be in Ireland for all but six weeks of the last year before my application;
- I need to spend 1,460 days in Ireland during the previous eight years.

But then the final part: is this now counting *years* or *days*? It would be a struggle to stay in Ireland for all but six weeks per year *each year*, but not a struggle to rack up 1,460 days in Ireland in five years.

---

Originally posted on Law StackExchange: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77846/irish-citizenship-residency-requirements. Someone there recommended asking here.

Comment: As a UK citizen, are you sure you even need an employment permit to work in the Republic of Ireland (see, e.g. Q1.2 of [this](https://enterprise.gov.ie/en/Publications/Publication-files/Employment-Permits-FAQs-2020.pdf)), and the reckonable residence requirement applies to you? [This page](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/becoming_an_irish_citizen_through_naturalisation.html#l6615c) mentions all period of residence counts for UK citizens. Will expand as answer when I get the time.

Comment: @B.Liu Yes, sure, I was being a bit lazy with my phrasing. I just meant that it's super easy to be allowed to work in Ireland as a UK citizen, because of the Common Travel Area (CTA) stuff. I did, however, miss the part on EEA/Swiss/UK citizen! `:person_facepalming:` I'm not 100% sure what "You have to show your residence by enclosing documentary evidence of your history in Ireland" means. Maybe just electricity bills for the last five years counts! If you wouldn't mind expanding on this section, I'd be super appreciative. Sorry for being dumb and missing this section `:P`

Comment: The link to the list of documents that can be used was a bit hard to find.

Comment: @B.Liu Mark has written an extremely helpful answer. Don't feel any social pressure to expand your comment, unless there is something particular you wish to add. They seem to have covered everything perfectly `:)`

Comment: Nothing to add to @MarkJohnson 's answer. I believe in having good answers on the stack whoever writes it, I also am keen in making sure we are not answering XY problems!

Comment: Thank you, both, for your help. And your patience, as I had clearly got myself in a muddle reading my own link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then the final part: is this now counting years or days?

Days, since the calculator returns the amount of days, the printout of which you must submit togeather with your application.

> [Naturalisation Residency Calculator](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/naturalisation-residency-calculator/)
>
> - Residence in the State (Your target is **1825 or 1826 days** over 9 years)

---

The **Calculating reckonable residence** doesn't apply to **EEA, UK and Swiss nationals** accourding to the text inside your link:

> If you are citizen of an EEA country, Switzerland **or the UK**, you *do not have to enclose a ‘reckonable residence’ calculation with your application*. You have to show your residence by [enclosing documentary evidence](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/how-to-become-a-citizen/become-an-irish-citizen-by-naturalisation/proofs-of-residence/) of your history in Ireland. The application form has a list of documents that are suitable for this purpose.
>
> The EEA includes the EU and Norway, Iceland and Lichtenstein.
>
> If you are a citizen of the EEA, Switzerland or the UK, you do not have to register for an Irish Residence Permit. All periods of residence in Ireland are counted towards naturalisation. You do not have to include a printout from the reckonable residence calculator with your application.

Inside the [online residency calculator](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/naturalisation-residency-calculator/) link:

> **UK, EU, EEA & Swiss nationals**
> Do not use this calculator. Instead, you must [submit various documents](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/how-to-become-a-citizen/become-an-irish-citizen-by-naturalisation/proofs-of-residence/) that prove the length of your residence in Ireland.

There the **Proof of Residency** is described,  that also contains a link to an Excel file that contains a list of documents that can be used as
[Proof of Identity and Proof's establishing lawful Residency in the state](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/2022-Scorecard-for-proofs-re-Identity-and-Residency.xlsx) (xlsx).

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that's amazing. I feel pretty silly for not seeing the EEA/UK/Swiss part... Your "enclosing documentary evidence" link wasn't so obvious, though: I can only see it now by going onto the calculator... even though it basically says, "No need to use calculator if UK citizen." That's extremely helpful, thank you

Comment: @SamOT I only found it because I wanted to see what the result of the calculator was to answer your main question. All roads lead to Rome.

Comment: Somehow, I didn't even see the online calculator ¬_¬ thank you for your helpful answer, where some might have just said, "Just read your own link more carefully: all your questions are answered there." Just so I'm completely clear, there is no issue with how long I spend in Ireland? I just need to get 150 points, eg from employment plus bank and credit card statements (with their conditions in your linked spreadsheet)